# ExecuteXmlReader and null Resultset Throws TargetInvocationException

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, exception, null, resultset

I'm calling a stored procedure on a SQL Server 2005 database which returns an XML resultset. Sometimes it will return an null resultset becuase there are not rows to return. When this happens athe ExecuteXmlReader method throws a TargetInvocationException. This seems to be a known issue (see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/5e90e3c0-605b-406d-848a-dea7b16f458e/).
What is the best way to handle this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 3 choices

1. Modify **stored procedure** to return a dummy/empty value
2. Modify **code** - catch exception and do nothing - or log error
3. Use **DataSet** - You should get an empty DataSet so just check if DataSet is empty or not.

As a related SO post for the 3rd choice, here is a SO question on how to check if DataSet is empty or not

[In C#, what is the best way to test if a dataset is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833/in-c-what-is-the-best-way-to-test-if-a-dataset-is-empty)