# Gridview check if its empty or null

Tags: c#, asp.net

hello I have a code that pulls the data to the gridview using a dataset, what is the best way to check if the Gridview is empty and if it is to not throw an error.. Right  now my gridview has the setting to show a message if its empty.. but I just want to null and empty check after attempting to get the data in the dataset

```
 Students students = new Students();
    DataSet studentsList = students.GetAllStudents();
    GridView1.DataSource = studentsList;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, why not just check [if the DataSet is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833/in-c-what-is-the-best-way-to-test-if-a-dataset-is-empty), before you bind it to the GridView?

If it is, just don't bind it.

```
DataSet studentsList = students.GetAllStudents();
bool empty = IsEmpty(studentsList); // check DataSet here, see the link above
if(empty)
{
    GridView1.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    GridView1.DataSource = studentsList;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the returned row if its has data or not:

```
 DataSet studentsList = students.GetAllStudents();

 if(studentList.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) //COUNT DATASET RECORDS
{
    GridView1.DataSource = studentsList;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
   lblError.Text = "NO RECORDS FOUND!";
}
```

Regards